# Bigquery API: How to provide schema to load_table_from_storage call

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

What is the best way to specify schema when uploading json hosted on Google Cloud Storage to Bigquery using `load_table_from_storage`?

The list of fields is quite bi and complex and i already have it in a format like this:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/personsDataSchema.json

Is there any way i can provide the schema in this format in Python? And if yes what syntax should i be foollowing? I tried various options none of thos worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that [load_table_from_storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_gcs.py#L35) receives in the `destination` input an object of the class `google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table`. This is where you should have your schema specified.

As an example, if "bqc" is your BigQuery Client object, then this creates a Table object:

```
ds = bqc.dataset('dataset_name')
table = ds.table('table_name')
```

Now let's say you have this data in your json file to work with:

```
{"user_id": "1", "visitid": 1, "hits": [{"hitNumber": 1, "type": "PAGE"}, {"hitNumber": 2, "type": "PAGE"}]}
{"user_id": "2", "visitid": 1, "hits": [{"hitNumber": 1, "type": "EVENT"}, {"hitNumber": 2, "type": "PAGE"}]}
```

Then defining its schema would be done like so:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery.schema import SchemaField
f1 = SchemaField('user_id', 'STRING')
f2 = SchemaField('visitid', 'INTEGER')
f3 = SchemaField('hits', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED', fields=[SchemaField('hitNumber', 'INTEGER'), SchemaField('type', 'STRING')])

table.schema = [f1, f2, f3]
table.create()
```